# check a textbox for invalid characters using js and regular expressions

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am having a hard time figuring out how RegExp work.

I need to rewrite some ASP code into html and js, and I've hit an obstacle in this part:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" id="RegExpValidator" controltovalidate="FileName" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="[^#%&*:<>?/{|}]+">
```

Now, what I do is create an input textbox which will run a js function whenever its content is changing.

```
<input type="text" id="fileNameTextBox" class="ms-input" size="35" maxlength="123" onchange="regexValidator(this);"/>

function regexValidator(control) {
            var val = $(control).val();
            if(val == undefined || val == '') {

                $(control).attr("class", "invalid");
            } 
            else { 
            // Regex stuff goes in here
            }
        }
```

Now, for the life of me I can't figure out how to construct the regular expression. The ValidationExpression field i assume checks for invalid characters though it doesn't seem to be a properly constructed regex, and I can't figure out how to write it into a proper one to use with js. Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the regex to check for invalid characters in the field, you can use this.

`^.*?(?=[\^#%&$\*:<>\?/\{\|\}]).*$` This will give you a match if there is at least one invalid character.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. Now you just need to make sure, that your string **only** consists of valid characters. Do this by adding anchors for the beginning and end of string, thus ensuring that the repeated sequence covers the whole string:

```
ValidationExpression="^[^#%&*:<>?/{|}]+$"
```

**EDIT:** I just realised that you probably also want to know how to create a regular expression from a string. You can simply pass a string to a regex constructor:

```
new RegExp(validationExpressionGoesHere);
```

Comment: This checks if all the characters in the field are invalid, not just for *any* character

Comment: The character class is negated, so it will check if all the characters are valid.

Answer (score 2):

`[^#%&*:<>?/{|}]+` looks like a valid expression to me (although typically regular expressions are enclosed in forward-slashes). It's basically checking to see of the filename contains any of the illegal characters within the square brackets (apart from the caret `^` which indicates negation).

```
function regexValidator(control) {
        var val = $(control).val();
        if(val == undefined || val == '') {

            $(control).attr("class", "invalid");
        } 
        else if(val.match(/[^#%&*:<>?/{|}]+/)) {
            // Valid
        }
        else {
            // Invalid
        }
    }
```