# Creating a character restriction on an textbox with javascript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [check a textbox for invalid characters using js and regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931617/check-a-textbox-for-invalid-characters-using-js-and-regular-expressions)

I want creating a character restriction on an textbox for the character <,>,' is not allowed with javascript and can i do it with regex code ?

i found this link and solve
[check a textbox for invalid characters using js and regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931617/check-a-textbox-for-invalid-characters-using-js-and-regular-expressions)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What this code doesn't do that you want it to do?

Comment: I want creating a character restriction on an textbox for the character <,>,' is not allowed with javascript and can i do it with regex code ? thanks for advance =]

Comment: To the editors: note there is some content present in r#1 that was accidentally removed in r#2. As long as there is a suggested request pending, no more edits can be done.

Comment: -1 for removing your previous attempt (instead of marking it as such) from the question. Please don't remove content from the question. If I only regard the latest revision: "What have you tried? We're not a code factory. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with javascript by just checking for the position of these charactors. No need for regular expressions.

```
function checkText(txt)
{
    if (txt.indexOf('<')>=0) return false;
    if (txt.indexOf('>')>=0) return false;
    if (txt.indexOf('\'')>=0) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Now you can use this function to check the input value of the textare using `onchange` or `onkeyup`. Binding with jquery is possible if you use it.

Just keep in mind that checking with javascript is not secure. Its just a way to inform a user quickly of an error. You should do the same checks serverside aswell.